# Is it possible to get element's numerical index in its parent node without looping?

Tags: javascript, dom

Normally I'm doing it this way:

```
for(i=0;i<elem.parentNode.length;i++) {
  if (elem.parentNode[i] == elem) //.... etc.. etc...
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could count siblings...
The childNodes list includes text **and** element nodes-

```
function whichChild(elem){
    var  i= 0;
    while((elem=elem.previousSibling)!=null) ++i;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: "*for most nodes*" Is there ever an instance where an element could have more than one parentNode?

Comment: to avoid counting whitespaces in children list, use previousElementSibling instead

Comment: awesome! - a very elegant solution

Answer (score 62):

```js
function getChildIndex(node) {
  return Array.prototype.indexOf.call(node.parentNode.childNodes, node);
}
```

This seems to work in Opera 11, Firefox 4, Chromium 10. Other browsers untested. It will throw TypeError if node has no parent (add a check for `node.parentNode !== undefined` if you care about that case).

Of course, `Array.prototype.indexOf` does still loop, just within the function call. It's impossible to do this without looping.

---

**Note:** If you want to obtain the index of a child `Element`, you can modify the function above by changing `childNodes` to `children`.

```js
function getChildElementIndex(node) {
  return Array.prototype.indexOf.call(node.parentNode.children, node);
}
```

Comment: Nice and short but note that it won't work on IE < 9. It is generally discouraged to apply `Array.prototype` methods on [host objects](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#hostObject), since the [Specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.14) cannot guarantee they will properly work: "Whether the indexOf function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent."

Comment: `indexOf` does scan the whole array so technically it doesn't really answer the question. But since indexOf is a built-in function, it will run faster than writing your own loop.

Comment: Beware that parentNode.childNodes may contain `text` nodes and you may not want them to be considered.

Comment: Should be `.children` instead of `.childNodes`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter it's not clear what the question is asking, given it's code doesn't work, whether it wants the nth child element or the nth child node

Comment: @gsnedders I can't think of a use case for wanting to include text nodes. I think that if whitespace between elements changes the return value of this function 99% of people will consider it a bug.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I modified the response above to include your suggestion.

Comment: Pretty awesome solution !

Answer (score 54):

#### Option #1

You can use the [`Array.from()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of elements to an array. From there, you can use the native [`.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in order to get the index:

```
function getElementIndex (element) {
  return Array.from(element.parentNode.children).indexOf(element);
}
```

If you want the node index (as oppose to the element's index), then replace the [`children` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) with the [`childNodes` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes):

```
function getNodeIndex (element) {
  return Array.from(element.parentNode.childNodes).indexOf(element);
}
```

#### Option #2

You can use the [`.call()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to invoke the array type's native `.indexOf()` method. This is how the [`.index()` method](https://api.jquery.com/index/) is implemented in jQuery if you look at the source code.

```
function getElementIndex(element) {
  return [].indexOf.call(element.parentNode.children, element);
}
```

Likewise, using the `childNodes` property in place of the `children` property:

```
function getNodeIndex (element) {
  return [].indexOf.call(element.parentNode.childNodes, element);
}
```

#### Option #3

You can also use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
function getElementIndex (element) {
  return [...element.parentNode.children].indexOf(element);
}
```

```
function getNodeIndex (element) {
  return [...element.parentNode.childNodes].indexOf(element);
}
```

Comment: Option #1 here is the only one listed on this page that worked for me.

Comment: I use it with `onclick=fmyfunc(e);` with multiple `button`  elements and always get 0 value.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get the index of a node within its parent without looping in *some* manner, be that a `for`-loop, an `Array` method like `indexOf` or `forEach`, or something else.  An index-of operation in the DOM is linear-time, not constant-time.

More generally, if list mutations are possible (and the DOM certainly supports mutation), it's generally impossible to provide an index-of operation that runs in constant time.  There are two common implementation tactics: linked lists (usually doubly) and arrays.  Finding an index using a linked list requires a walk.  Finding an index using an array requires a scan.  Some engines will cache indexes to reduce time needed to compute `node.childNodes[i]`, but this won't help you if you're searching for a node.  Not asking the question is the best policy.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got it, but:

- make sure that variable "i" is declared with `var`
- use `===` instead of `==` in the comparison

Comment: ... because a variable not declared with `var` or attached to an object is on the global object (`window`), and `==` returns true for "kind of equal" values with an unpredictable (but well-documented and insane) definition of what that means.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection input elements with the same **name** (like `<textarea name="text_field[]"`…) in your form and you want to get the exact numeric index of the field that triggered an event:

```
function getElementIdxFromName(elem, parent) {
    var elms = parent[elem.name];
    var  i = 0;
    if (elms.length === undefined) // there is only one element with this name in the document
        return 0;
    while((elem!=elms[i])) i++;
    return i;
}
```

Getting numeric id of an element from a collection of elements with the same **class name**:

```
function getElementIdxFromClass(elem, cl) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
    var  i = 0;
    if (elems.length > 0) {
        while((elem!=elems[i])) i++;
        return i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
let element = document.getElementById("your-element-id");
let indexInParent = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.parentNode.parentNode.children).indexOf(element.parentNode));
```