# How to determine the index of the element in its parent node?

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is the example code:

```
<div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
     ....

</div>
```

I just need to find the index of the the inner div in the parent div, passed to function as **this**.

p.s. I checked the other question which is same:
[Is it possible to get element's numerical index in its parent node without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649699/is-it-possible-to-get-elements-numerical-index-in-its-parent-node-without-loopi)

however that method suggested did not work for me..
[Is it possible to get element's numerical index in its parent node without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649699/is-it-possible-to-get-elements-numerical-index-in-its-parent-node-without-loopi/4649781#4649781)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example using plain JS (no jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xgk4y/.  Click on any of the divs to see the index returned from `countPrevSiblings()`.

And the code from that:

```
function countPrevSiblings(elem) {
    var i = 0;
    while((elem = elem.previousSibling) != null) {
        // count element nodes only
        if (elem.nodeType == 1) {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get index by using [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) jquery function, if this is not working for you, explain you question bit more.

Sample : `$(this).index($(this).siblings());`

Comment: [tag:jQuery] wasn't tagged on this question, which typically means OP wants a pure-js solution.