# Get the active class index from list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, activerecord

I want to get the active class index using JavaScript. i done it with jQuery but i need it with JavaScript.

I done it with jQuery like this.

```
<li class="list"> .... </li>
<li class="list"> .... </li>
<li class="list"> .... </li>
<li class="list active"> .... </li>
<li class="list"> .... </li>

<script>
$('li.active').index()
</script>
```

i want same with javascipt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to select all the required elements. Then convert it to array using javascript and then use `indexOf()` on that.

```js
const list = [...document.querySelectorAll('.list')];
const active = document.querySelector('.list.active');
console.log(list.indexOf(active))
```

```html
<li class="list"> .... </li>
<li class="list"> .... </li>
<li class="list"> .... </li>
<li class="list active"> .... </li>
<li class="list"> .... </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.call()` method to invoke the array type's native `.indexOf()` method. This is how the `.index()` method is implemented in `jQuery` if you look at the source code. [more about the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649699/is-it-possible-to-get-elements-numerical-index-in-its-parent-node-without-loopi)

```js
function getChildNumber(node) {
 return [].indexOf.call(node.parentNode.children, node);
}
let activeNode = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
console.log(getChildNumber(activeNode));
```

```html
<li class="list"> .... </li>
<li class="list"> .... </li>
<li class="list"> .... </li>
<li class="list active"> .... </li>
<li class="list"> .... </li>
```