# How to get index of div in parent div?

Tags: javascript, html

is there any way to get index of clicked div in parent div?

Here's an example:

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div id="1" class="child"></div>
    <div id="2" class="child"></div>
    <div id="3" class="child"></div>
    <div id="4" class="child"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
    var child = document.getElementsByClassName("child");

    for(var i=0; i < parent.length; i++){
        parent[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
            console.log(e.target)
            console.log(e.target.parentNode)
        });
    }
</script>
```

What I mean is, is there any way to get index of clicked div? For example, if I would click div with id "1", it would print "0" in console since its index is 0. If I would click div with id "2", it would print "1" in console since its index is 1, and so on.

Is there any way to do this? (without using attributes)

Comment: Your code doesn't really demonstrate what you're talking about because you're looping through `parent` elements, and not `child` elements. I suggest using `var parent = document.querySelector('.parent'); var children = parent.querySelectorAll('.child');` then loop through `children` There are ways of doing this (making `children` an array using `var kids = Array.from(children)` and using `console.log(kids.indexOf(e.target))`, but the question is, why do it that way rather than when you are adding the child elements themselves, via attributes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get child node index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913927/get-child-node-index)

Comment: This smells 99% like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is behind your question, what are you trying to achieve you think you need the index for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get element's numerical index in its parent node without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649699/is-it-possible-to-get-elements-numerical-index-in-its-parent-node-without-loopi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the child inside it's `parent.children`

```js
var child = document.getElementById('findme');
var parent = child.parentNode;

var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent.children, child);
console.log(index);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child" id="findme"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Using ES6 [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex);

```js
var child = document.getElementById('findme');
var parent = child.parentNode;

var index = Array.prototype.findIndex.call(parent.children, (c) => c === child);
console.log(index);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child" id="findme"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

However, this could give some issues on eg [IE](https://caniuse.com/?search=findindex).

Comment: ES6 has introduced `Array.prototype.findIndex()`.

Comment: ES6 also introduced `[...parent.children].indexOf(child)`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly, you have no idea how much time you just saved me!

Comment: There is no reason to bring up `findIndex` here.