# how to get index of parent div by clicking a button in child div by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

hello i have some nested divs. i want to know the index of div, which has class "row". when button is clicked i want to get div (class "raw" ) index of respected button. these div ( class raw ) are created by for loop so eventListener is not working.

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <button>Click</button>
     </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button>Click</button>
     </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button>Click</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

please help me

Comment: There are no elements with a `raw` class

Comment: What have you done so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: _"...are created by for loop so eventListener is not working."_ - Why shouldn't that work? -> [mcve]

Comment: Actually a dupe of: [JavaScript DOM: Find Element Index In Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761881/javascript-dom-find-element-index-in-container)

Comment: i tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66771371/how-to-get-index-of-div-in-parent-div . but its not working because this divs ( class raw ) are created by loop after the page load that's why it cant read value of parent and child variables because it is not present in the page at load time

Comment: _"i cant use addEventListener"_ - Forget that flawed assumption. You can execute JavaScript when ever you want. Even when the elements aren't in the DOM yet you can already add an event listener on a parent element - or just wait until the elements are in the DOM -> [Introduction to events - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Comment: @gauravjoshi check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70455549/17716837 I was having the same problem before, and this answer solves that.

Comment: maybe use defer attribute in script tag, or put the script tag in the end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript DOM: Find Element Index In Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761881/javascript-dom-find-element-index-in-container)

Answer (score 1):

1. if the parent element is clicked,

    we check then if one of the buttons if clicked (so we can have the correct index always correct!

```js
let rows = document.querySelectorAll(".row");

rows.forEach((el, index) => {
  // adding click event
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let isBtnClicked = [...el.querySelectorAll("button")].some(
      (btn) => e.target == btn,
    );

    // if the button is clicked this means is true
    console.log(isBtnClicked, index, document.querySelectorAll(".row")[index]);
  });
});
```

```css
/* delete this style, only debugging */

.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- 0 -->
  <div class="row">
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
  <!-- 1 -->
  <div class="row">
    <button>Click</button>

    <!-- to test also with more buttons -->
    <button>Click</button>
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
  <!-- 2 -->
  <div class="row">
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

2. if you want only the first button to be clicked, use this:

```js
// only buttons that are inside .row class container

// if you use :first-child or :last-child inside the selector, 
// the if there is 2 buttons it will add the event only in one 
// and this means the index is always correct!!
let RowButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".row button:first-child");

// for loop
RowButtons.forEach((btn, index) => {

  // adding click event
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {

    // getting the index of the button (technically is the same index of the .row)
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".row")[index]);
  });
});
```

```css
/* delete this style, only debugging */

.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- 0 -->
  <div class="row">
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
  <!-- 1 -->
  <div class="row">
    <button>Click</button>

    <!-- only first button will work using :first-child -->
    <button>this don't have event</button>
    <button>also this don't have event</button>
  </div>
  <!-- 2 -->
  <div class="row">
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

3. if you want only the first button, but with the first example logic

```js
let rows = document.querySelectorAll(".row");

rows.forEach((el, index) => {
  // adding click event
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // true means first button clicked, false not
    console.log(e.target == el.querySelector("button"))
  });
});
```

```css
/* delete this style, only debugging */

.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- 0 -->
  <div class="row">
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
  <!-- 1 -->
  <div class="row">
    <button>Click</button>

    <!-- only first button will work using :first-child -->
    <button>this don't have event</button>
    <button>also this don't have event</button>
  </div>
  <!-- 2 -->
  <div class="row">
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your affords but as i mentioned i cant use addEventListener because this divs ( class raw ) are created by loop after the page load that's why  it cant read value of RowButtons because it is not present in the page at load time

Comment: @gauravjoshi check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70455549/17716837 I was having the same problem before, and this answer solves that.