# Adding youtube href to calender Each Dates

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, calendar

Currently we are working on a online class website in which our client want to add recorded class ( classes going on online will be recorded and uploaded to YouTube in unlisted format ) videos to the the calendar dates. I will add the code of the calendar here.

Here am attaching the codepen link : https://codepen.io/internette/pen/YqJEjY

```html
<div class="yellow">
  <div id="calendar">
    <div id="toolbar"></div>
    <div id="color-picker" class="show"></div>
    <div id="dates" class="show">
      <div id="lastMt">&lsaquo;</div>
      <div id="nextMt">&rsaquo;</div>
      <div id="months-cont">
        <div id="months">
        <span class="active month">January</span><span class="month">February</span><span class="month">March</span><span class="month">April</span><span class="month">May</span><span class="month">June</span><span class="month">July</span><span class="month">August</span><span class="month">September</span><span class="month">October</span><span class="month">November</span><span class="month">December</span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div id="daysotweek">
        <div class="day">S</div>
        <div class="day">M</div>
        <div class="day">T</div>
        <div class="day">W</div>
        <div class="day">T</div>
        <div class="day">F</div>
        <div class="day">S</div>
      </div>
      <div id="days">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="info" class="hide">
      <div id="actual-date"></div>
      <div id="back"><</div>
        <div id="month-name"></div>
        <div id="weather">
          <div id="sun"></div>
          <div id="mountains"></div>
          <div id="rain">
            <div class="raindrop" id="drop-1"></div>
            <div class="raindrop center" id="drop-2"></div>
            <div class="raindrop center" id="drop-3"></div>
            <div class="raindrop" id="drop-4"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="temp">57&deg;<span>F</span></div>
        </div>
        <div id="bg-card">
          <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
      <div id="card">
        <div class="content">
          <div id="event-name"></div>
          <div id="event-details">
          <div class="col-3">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h3>Location</h3>
            <p>12345 Generic Ave., Some City, Some State, 12345
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h3>Time</h3>
            <p> 12:00 AM </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h3>Attendee</h3>
            <p>Me, You, and 2+</p>
          </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>
      
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="colors" class="hide">
      <div id="close">&times;</div>
      <p>Choose theme color</p>
      <div class="color" id="salmon"></div>
      <div class="color" id="dkpink"></div>
      <div class="color" id="red"></div>
      <div class="color" id="redorg"></div>
      <div class="color" id="orange"></div>
      <div class="color" id="orgylw"></div>
      <div class="color active" id="yellow"></div>
      <div class="color" id="green"></div>
      <div class="color" id="aqua"></div>
      <div class="color" id="teal"></div>
      <div class="color" id="sltbl"></div>
      <div class="color" id="pwdbl"></div>
      <div class="color" id="blue"></div>
      <div class="color" id="purple"></div>
      <div class="color" id="dkprpl"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am looking for is when the Date in the calender is clicked, toggle space should display a href of the youtube video.

Comment: And where and why are you stuck?

Comment: Am new to Javascript .. How to add < a href> youtube link to each dates in the calendar ??

Comment: Am new to Javascript .. How to add < a href> youtube link to each dates in the calendar ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the anchor tag the same way you've added the rest of the elements. I've modified your code to show a link to youtube. Please check the code snippet:

```js
var allMonths, dayArray = [],
  click = 0,
  dotw = [/Sun/gi, /Mon/gi, /Tue/gi, /Wed/gi, /Thu/gi, /Fri/gi, /Sat/gi];

function getAllDays(month, year) {
  var date = new Date(year, month, 1);
  var days = [];
  while (date.getMonth() === month) {
    var dayToPush = new Date(date);
    days.push(dayToPush);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return days;
}

function getYear() {
  var d = new Date();
  var curYear = d.getFullYear();
  return curYear;
}

function addElements(query, id) {
  //for onload, use activeIndex+1 as query value
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '';
  var allDays = getAllDays((query), getYear());
  for (var i = 0; i < allDays.length; i++) {
    allDays[i] = allDays[i].toString();
  }
  var stopNow = false,
    counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < dotw.length; i++) {
    if (allDays[0].match(dotw[i])) {
      stopNow = true;
    } else {
      if (!stopNow) {
        counter += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    allDays.unshift(" ");
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < allDays.length; i++) {
    var singleDay = document.createElement('div');
    singleDay.className = 'day';
    singleDay.dataset.title = '';
    singleDay.dataset.location = '';
    //Parse Day
    if (allDays[i] !== " ") {
      var dayOTW = allDays[i].split(' ')[2];
      if (dayOTW.charAt(0) === "0") {
        allDays[i] = dayOTW.replace(/0/gi, '');
      } else {
        allDays[i] = dayOTW;
      }
    }
    singleDay.innerHTML = allDays[i];
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(singleDay);
  }
  var allOfDays = document.querySelectorAll('#days .day');
  var dayArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < allOfDays.length; i++) {
    if (i === 6 || i === 13 || i === 20 || i === 27 || i === 34) {
      // dayArray.push(i);
      // console.log(allOfDays[i]);
      allOfDays[i].outerHTML += '<div class="day-details"><div id="input-arrow"></div><div class="input"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkhPuH8G5Hg">CLICK ME</a></div></div>'
    }
  }
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += '<div class="day-details"><div id="input-arrow"></div><div class="input"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkhPuH8G5Hg">CLICK ME</a></div><div style="clear:both"></div>';
}
//Thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649699/is-it-possible-to-get-elements-numerical-index-in-its-parent-node-without-loopi
function whichChild(elem) {
  var i = 0;
  while ((elem = elem.previousSibling) != null) ++i;
  return i;
}
window.onload = function() {
  allMonths = document.querySelectorAll('.month');
  var monthCont = document.getElementById('months');
  for (var i = 0; i < allMonths.length; i++) {
    allMonths[i].innerHTML += ' ' + getYear();
  }
  addElements(0, 'days');
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var currentActive = document.querySelector('#months .month.active');
  var calWidth = Number(getComputedStyle(currentActive).width.replace(/px/gi, ''));
  var activeIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < allMonths.length; i++) {
    if (allMonths[i].innerHTML === currentActive.innerHTML) {
      activeIndex = i;
    }
  }
  if (e.target.id === 'nextMt') {
    if (activeIndex < 11) {
      document.querySelector('#months .month:first-child').style.marginLeft = -(calWidth * (activeIndex + 1)) + 'px';
      currentActive.className = 'month';
      allMonths[activeIndex + 1].className += ' active';
      addElements((activeIndex + 1), 'days');
    } else {
      document.querySelector('#months .month:first-child').style.marginLeft = '0px';
      currentActive.className = 'month';
      allMonths[0].className += ' active';
      addElements(0, 'days');
    }
  } else if (e.target.id === 'lastMt') {
    if (activeIndex > 0) {
      document.querySelector('#months .month:first-child').style.marginLeft = -(calWidth * (activeIndex - 1)) + 'px';
      currentActive.className = 'month';
      allMonths[activeIndex - 1].className += ' active';
      addElements((activeIndex - 1), 'days');
    } else {
      document.querySelector('#months .month:first-child').style.marginLeft = -(calWidth * 11) + 'px';
      currentActive.className = 'month';
      allMonths[11].className += ' active';
      addElements(11, 'days');
    }
  }
  if (e.target.id === 'color-picker') {
    document.querySelector('#dates.show').className = 'hide';
    document.getElementById('colors').className = 'show';
    e.target.className = 'hide';
  }
  if (e.target.id === 'back') {
    document.getElementById('color-picker').className = document.getElementById('color-picker').className.replace(/hide/gi, 'show');
    document.getElementById('info').className = document.getElementById('info').className.replace(/show/gi, 'hide');
    document.getElementById('dates').className = document.getElementById('dates').className.replace(/hide/gi, 'show');
  }
  if (e.target.className === 'color') {
    var allColors = document.querySelectorAll('.color');
    for (var i = 0; i < allColors.length; i++) {
      allColors[i].className = 'color';
      if (allColors[i].id === e.target.id) {
        allColors[i].className += ' active';
      }
    }
    document.querySelector('body > div').className = 'prev-' + document.querySelector('body > div').className + ' ' + document.querySelector('.color.active').id;
    document.querySelector('body > div').className = document.querySelector('.color.active').id;

  }
  if (e.target.id === 'close') {
    if (e.target.parentNode.id === 'colors') {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.parentNode.className = 'hide';
      document.getElementById('dates').className = 'show';
      document.getElementById('color-picker').className = 'show';
    }
  }
  if (e.target.className.match(/day/gi) && e.target.parentNode.id === 'days') {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.day-details.expanded').length; i++) {
      document.querySelectorAll('.day-details.expanded')[i].className = document.querySelectorAll('.day-details.expanded')[i].className.replace(/ expanded/gi, '');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.day.expanded').length; i++) {
      if (document.querySelectorAll('.day.expanded')[i].innerHTML !== e.target.innerHTML) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.day.expanded')[i].className = document.querySelectorAll('.day.expanded')[i].className.replace(/ expanded/gi, '');
      }
    }
    if (e.target.className.match(/expanded/gi)) {
      e.target.className = e.target.className.replace(/ expanded/gi, '');
    } else {
      e.target.className += ' expanded';

    }
    var currElm = e.target;
    while (!currElm.nextSibling.className.match(/day-details/gi)) {
      currElm = currElm.nextSibling;
    }
    currElm.nextSibling.className += ' expanded';
    currElm.nextSibling.childNodes[0].style.marginLeft = (e.target.offsetLeft + 8) + 'px';
  }
  if (e.target.className === 'input') {
    e.target.outerHTML = '<input type="text"/>';
    document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded input').focus();
  }
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A' && e.target.parentNode.className === 'input') {
    click += 1;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (click > 1) {

        document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded .input').outerHTML = '<input type="text" value="' + document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded .input a').innerHTML + '"/>';
        document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded input').focus();
        document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded input').setSelectionRange(document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded input').value.length, document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded input').value.length);
      } else if (click === 1) {

        document.getElementById('color-picker').className = document.getElementById('color-picker').className.replace(/show/gi, 'hide');
        document.getElementById('month-name').innerHTML = document.querySelector('.month.active').innerHTML.replace(' 2016', '');
        document.getElementById('info').className = 'show';
        document.getElementById('actual-date').style.left = document.querySelector('.day.expanded').offsetLeft + 'px';
        document.getElementById('actual-date').style.top = document.querySelector('.day.expanded').offsetTop + 'px';
        document.getElementById('dates').className = 'hide';
        TweenMax.to("#actual-date", ((document.querySelector('.day.expanded').offsetTop * 2.5) / document.getElementById('calendar').clientHeight), {
          bezier: {
            values: [{
              x: 0,
              y: 0
            }, {
              x: (3 * (document.getElementById('calendar').clientWidth - document.querySelector('.day.expanded').offsetLeft - 28)) / 4,
              y: -(1 * (document.querySelector('.day.expanded').offsetTop - 9)) / 4
            }, {
              x: document.getElementById('calendar').clientWidth - document.querySelector('.day.expanded').offsetLeft - 26,
              y: -(document.querySelector('.day.expanded').offsetTop - 7)
            }]
          }
        });
        document.getElementById('actual-date').innerHTML = document.querySelector('.day.expanded').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('event-name').innerHTML = document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded .input a').innerHTML;
        document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded').className = document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded').className.replace(/ expanded/, '');
        document.querySelector('.day.expanded').className = document.querySelector('.day.expanded').className.replace(/ expanded/, '');
      }
      click = 0;
    }, 500);
  }
});
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    document.querySelector('.day.expanded').dataset.title = document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded input').value;
    if (document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded input').value.length > 0) {
      document.querySelector('.day.expanded').className += ' has-event';
      document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded input').outerHTML = '<div class="input"><a>' + document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded input').value + '</a></div>';
    } else {
      if (document.querySelector('.day.expanded').className.match(/ has-event/gi)) {
        document.querySelector('.day.expanded').className = document.querySelector('.day.expanded').className.replace(/ has-event/gi, '');
      }
      document.querySelector('.day-details.expanded input').outerHTML = '<div class="input"></div>';
    }
    click = 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://codepen.io/internette/pen/YqJEjY.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="yellow">
  <div id="calendar">
    <div id="toolbar"></div>
    <div id="color-picker" class="show"></div>
    <div id="dates" class="show">
      <div id="lastMt">&lsaquo;</div>
      <div id="nextMt">&rsaquo;</div>
      <div id="months-cont">
        <div id="months">
          <span class="active month">January</span><span class="month">February</span><span class="month">March</span><span class="month">April</span><span class="month">May</span><span class="month">June</span><span class="month">July</span><span class="month">August</span>
          <span
            class="month">September</span><span class="month">October</span><span class="month">November</span><span class="month">December</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="daysotweek">
        <div class="day">S</div>
        <div class="day">M</div>
        <div class="day">T</div>
        <div class="day">W</div>
        <div class="day">T</div>
        <div class="day">F</div>
        <div class="day">S</div>
      </div>
      <div id="days">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="info" class="hide">
      <div id="actual-date"></div>
      <div id="back">
        <</div>
          <div id="month-name"></div>
          <div id="weather">
            <div id="sun"></div>
            <div id="mountains"></div>
            <div id="rain">
              <div class="raindrop" id="drop-1"></div>
              <div class="raindrop center" id="drop-2"></div>
              <div class="raindrop center" id="drop-3"></div>
              <div class="raindrop" id="drop-4"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="temp">57&deg;<span>F</span></div>
          </div>
          <div id="bg-card">
            <div class="content"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="card">
            <div class="content">
              <div id="event-name"></div>
              <div id="event-details">
                <div class="col-3">
                  <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <h3>Location</h3>
                  <p>12345 Generic Ave., Some City, Some State, 12345
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <h3>Time</h3>
                  <p> 12:00 AM </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                  <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <h3>Attendee</h3>
                  <p>Me, You, and 2+</p>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="colors" class="hide">
        <div id="close">&times;</div>
        <p>Choose theme color</p>
        <div class="color" id="salmon"></div>
        <div class="color" id="dkpink"></div>
        <div class="color" id="red"></div>
        <div class="color" id="redorg"></div>
        <div class="color" id="orange"></div>
        <div class="color" id="orgylw"></div>
        <div class="color active" id="yellow"></div>
        <div class="color" id="green"></div>
        <div class="color" id="aqua"></div>
        <div class="color" id="teal"></div>
        <div class="color" id="sltbl"></div>
        <div class="color" id="pwdbl"></div>
        <div class="color" id="blue"></div>
        <div class="color" id="purple"></div>
        <div class="color" id="dkprpl"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you answered what i was trying to ask.. one more doubt is how to  add different youtube links for different dates

Comment: Where are you storing your calendar data? (map of the dates and related YouTube link(s))

Comment: Assuming you have the data in a database, you can expose an API endpoint that accepts a date as a parameter, which can be called when a date on your calendar view is clicked. The endpoint should return the YouTube link(s) available for that specific date, which in-turn you can append to the toggle space.

Comment: Its a static website.. am not using any database...

Comment: If it's static.. you'll have to create a calendar object that maps a date to a list of links. Which you can search from upon clicking a specific date.