# Getting the index value of a specific div in a group

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I'm creating a group of `<div>`'s that have separate content:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item myClass"></div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to get the specific index value of a `<div>` when it has a certain class applied to (e.g., `myClass`)

```
const item = document.querySelector(".container__item");
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".container__item");
const myClass = document.querySelector(".myClass");
```

I'm looping through the collection of items but not able to get the index value, e.g., `0, 1, 2`. FYI, I'll be converting those values to `1, 2, 3`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  var hasClass = item[i]classList.contains(showItem);
  if (hasClass) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: you're iterating over `item` instead of `items` in your for loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get element's numerical index in its parent node without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649699/is-it-possible-to-get-elements-numerical-index-in-its-parent-node-without-loopi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over `item` instead of `items` in your for loop.  I added some ID's just for debugging to show you.  You're also missing a period after the index [i] before accessing classList.

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".container__item");

for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log( items[i].id );
  
  var hasClass = items[i].classList.contains('myClass');
  if (hasClass) {
    console.log('Index: ' + i);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="container__item" id="div2"></div>
  <div class="container__item myClass" id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element with the `container` class and loop over all its [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) and then grab the index of those children where the `className` [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) `myClass`.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

Array.from(container.children).forEach((c, i) => {
  if (c.className.includes("myClass")) {
    console.log(i + 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item myClass"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item myClass"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item myClass"></div>
</div>
```

You can also do it using [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), as shown below:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

Array.from(container.children).forEach((c, i) => {
  if (c.classList.contains("myClass")) {
    console.log(i + 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item myClass"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item myClass"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item myClass"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and subsequently [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the element list:

```js
const myClassElementsWithIndexes = 
  [...document.querySelectorAll(`.container .container__item`)]
    .map( (item, i) => ({elem: item, index: i}) )
    .filter(item => item.elem.classList.contains(`myClass`) );

console.log(myClassElementsWithIndexes);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item myClass"></div>
</div>
```