# how to find index of nested element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to find the index of the `p` element with id `tea2` with reference to its parent `div` element.

For example, the id `tea2` index should be `1` as reference to parent `div` element. Note: I have to omit these "br" tags in indexing.

```js
let index = $('#tea2').index();
console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <p>Milk</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="hot" id="tea">Tea</p>
  <p class="hot" id="favorite">Coffee</p>
</div>
<div class="">
  <p>Milk</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="hot" id="tea2">Tea</p>
  <p class="hot" id="favorite2">Coffee</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try to solve that?

Comment: `<br>` elements  cannot be children of `<ul>`.

Comment: I have tried like: $('#tea2').index(); but it gives me index from all over html. also tried to pass the argument in index(). but nothing works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649699/is-it-possible-to-get-elements-numerical-index-in-its-parent-node-without-loopi

Comment: You need to select only the `p` inside the parent `div` of `#tea2`, and then check for the index of your `#tea2` element in there. `$('#tea2').parent().find('p').index($('#tea2'))`

Answer (score 0):

First select the `#tea2` element. Then get the parent, the children of the parent, filter out the `<br>` tags and then find the index between the remaining children.

```js
const $tea2 = $('#tea2');
const index = $tea2.parent().children().filter(':not(br)').index($tea2);

console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <p>Milk</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="hot" id="tea">Tea</p>
  <p class="hot" id="favorite">Coffee</p>
</div>
<div class="">
  <p>Milk</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="hot" id="tea2">Tea</p>
  <p class="hot" id="favorite2">Coffee</p>
</div>
```