# How can I add multilanguage support across multiple HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html, multilingual, multi-page-application

I have a multi-page website. I tried to add multi-language support, and this is what I've got so far;

I have a div in 2 different HTML files.

```
<div class="langwrap" style="text-align: right;">
  <a href="#" data-lang="en">EN</a>
  <a href="#" class="activated" data-lang="tr">RU</a>
</div>
```

script.js file includes;

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const langwrap = document.querySelector(".langwrap"),
link = langwrap.querySelectorAll("a"),  
elements = {....} // All of my text in website.
let lang = localStorage.getItem("langwrap") || "tr";
const data = {EN: {}, RU:{} } //translations});


link.forEach((el, i) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        langwrap.querySelectorAll(".activated").forEach((element) => {
            element.classList.remove("activated");
        });
        el.classList.add("activated");

        const attr = el.dataset.lang;
        lang = attr;
        localStorage.setItem("langwrap", attr);
        localStorage.setItem("langIndex", i);
        changeLang(lang, elements);
    });
});

function changeLang(lang, elements) {
    document.documentElement.lang = lang;
    for (const key in elements) {
        if (elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const element = elements[key];
            if (element) {
                element.textContent = data[lang][key];
            }
        }
    }

}
});
```

When a user moves to another page language selection does not remain, how to handle that?
(no BE or framework)
Thanks

Comment: Save it in a cookie or on the server and return it from the server call to the new page perhaps?

Comment: Where do you expect `i` to come from inside this event handler? `localStorage.setItem("langIndex", i);`

Comment: Actually,  I have no idea :)
btw, tapping changes the language, but updating local storage parameters from inspect does not work.

Comment: I think you meant perhaps `link = document.querySelectorAll("a"),` to be `link = langwrap.querySelectorAll("a"),`

Comment: Sure that is right

Comment: You might consider getting the index using a call to find that among the siblings: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/4649699/125981 (NOT a duplicate more a way to get that ONE thing done)  You MAY not need to store that index if the dataset values are unique also.

Comment: Also HTML has an actual native attribute called `lang` so perhaps no need for the data-lang

Comment: @mplungjan — The `lang` attribute describes the language used inside the element. It doesn't describe what language JavaScript will change the entire document to when the link to the top of the page is clicked. (There's `hreflang` but that would only apply if the link was navigating to a new URL that held the translation of the current document).

Comment: It can still be used to indicate the language:  `<a href="#" lang="en">English</a><a href="#" lang="ru">Русский язык</a>`

Comment: Sure we can use it that way, but the implementation actually works when clicking the button, it just don't maintain the language

Comment: Stupid question, but are you calling `changeLang()` on page load? You are only calling that method inside the click listeners, according to the code you're shown. Also, do a `console.log(lang)` when loading the page, so you can see if that variable have updated.

Answer (score -1):

```
    if (lang === "en") {
    langwrap.querySelector(".activated").classList.remove("activated");
    link[0].classList.add("activated");
    changeLang("en", elements)
} else {
    langwrap.querySelector(".activated").classList.remove("activated");
    link[index].classList.add("activated");
    changeLang(lang, elements)
}
```

worked for me.

Comment: Answers with code should explain what the code does differently from the OP so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: Please explain your code. Otherwise it is really hard to understand what the code does, how it answers the question and a description of your solution should always be in an answer.